# How are most headers with content created?

Tags: html, css

I'm just barely learning how to code. I know there is more than one way to skin a cat, but what is the most efficient way to create a typical menu with lists, search fields, etc.?

I've been able to create all of the elements. I am having a very hard time getting the CSS correct to look the way I want.

Here is what my current project looks like. 
[image: Home Page]

This is what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Home Page Design]

Thanks for the help! Any tips for a beginner would also be appreciated. Thank you!

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lan="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset ="UTF-8">
            <link href = "racemonster.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                <title>Home</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="headerLeft">
            <h1>Name</h1>
        </div>
            <div class="headerRight">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="cart.html">Cart</a></li>
                    <li><a href="help.html">Help</a></li>
                    <li><a href="signIn.html">Sign In</a></li>
                    <li><a href="signUp.html">Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>


        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="home.html">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="5k10k.html">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="halfmarathon.html">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="marathon.html">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="gear.html">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Here is the css

```
.headerLeft{color:#C4D82D;font-family:sans-serif;background-color:#323232;width:100%;margin:0;padding:20px;top:0;left:0;}

.headerRight{color:#B1B3B5;font-family:sans-serif;background-color: #323232;width:100%;margin:0;padding:20px;top:0;left:0;}
.headerRight ul {list-style-type: none;}
.headerRight ul li{display: inline;margin-right: 20px}
.headerRight ul li a{text-decoration: none;font-family: sans-serif;color: #898B8E;background-color:#323232;}
.headerRight ul li a:hover{color:#B1B3B5;}

    .menu ul {list-style-type: none;width:100%; margin:0; padding-top:40px; padding-bottom:40px; background-color: #C4D82D}
    .menu ul li {display:inline;margin-right: 20px;}
    .menu ul li a {text-decoration: none;font-family: sans-serif;color:#323232;background-color: #C4D82D;}
    .menu ul li a:hover {color:#999B9D;}
```

Comment: You must share code. What have you tried exactly? What CSS have you done? what HTML have you done? It will be easier to help you out.

Comment: Use less padding and use floats for your content. Outside of that - it's impossible to help without code.

Answer (score 0):

## Updated Answer

Here is a solution... first check out my code (http://jsfiddle.net/ProgrammerKid/s01yuzm1/)

HTML

```
<div class="headers">
    <div class="headerLeft">
         <h1>Name</h1>

    </div>
    <div class="headerRight">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="cart.html">Cart</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="help.html">Help</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="signIn.html">Sign In</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="signUp.html">Sign Up</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="header-padding">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="home.html">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="5k10k.html">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="halfmarathon.html">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="marathon.html">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="gear.html">Link</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.headers {
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
}
.headerLeft {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 120px;
}
.headerRight {
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: right;
    height: 120px;
}
.header-padding {
    height: 120px;
}
```

What I like to do is group the two headers into one big `<div>` so that they both share a common parent (disregarding the `<body>`)... Then I added a CSS `float` property, and set their `width` to 50%. This will align them...

The `<div class="header-padding">[...]</div>` element is to provide the links sections with enough padding... Since we float the two `div`'s (`.headerRight`, and `.headerLeft`) the `links` sections would appear underneath the headers... therefore by placing the `header padding` element, we are providing the `links section` with enough space.

## Old Answer

There is no "correct" way to make a header

That being said, it would be really helpful to the people answering your question if you included the HTML/CSS/JS code...

For now I will use a very abstract method of conveying my tips to you...

If we said the element with the word "NAME" inside it was a `<div id="1"></div>` and the element in which your menu items are in would be `<div id="2"></div>`, and the links were `<div id="3"></div>`

Then here is what your CSS should look like:

```
#1 {
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
}

#2 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

the above will align both the elements together

and below we will reduce the padding to around 10px;

```
#3 {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

and that's all I can help you with for now until you upload your code

Comment: I uploaded my code. I appreciate the help, everyone. I'm brand new to this, but I know that good coding is about achieving the best results with efficient code. I know I'm probably being very inefficient and I wanted some thoughts and guidance on how to be more effective with my code to achieve a certain look.

Answer (score 0):

I have created css as you required it is very straightforward and easy to understand.

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dushyant099/57t0g146/)

```css
.container {
    background-color:#323232;
}
.title {
    color:#C4D82D;
    margin-left:40px;
}
.headerLeft {
    width:50%;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.headerRight {
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.headerRight ul li {
    display:inline;
    color:#B1B3B5;
}
.headerRight ul li a {
    color:#b1b3b5;
}
.headerRight ul li a:hover {
    color:#B1B3B5;
}
.menu {
    background-color:#C4D82D;
    height:50%;
    position:relative;
    padding-top:20px;
    margin:(auto, auto, 0, 0);
}
.menu ul li {
    display:inline;
}
.menu ul li a {
    color:#323232;
}
.menu ul li a:hover {
    color:#999B9D;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="headerLeft">
             <h1 class="title">Name</h1>

        </div>
        <div class="headerRight">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="cart.html">Cart |</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="help.html">Help |</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="signIn.html">Sign In |</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="signUp.html">Sign Up |</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```